# Unable to scan Beckhoff KL 2502 module

Tags: plc, twincat

I was trying to scan  Beckhoff KL 2502 (PWM op module) in my beckhoff system through by PC, but this module is not visible when I scan the devices. I added the respective xml file to the twincat folder and still it is not visible in the scan. I tried to add the module manually in the devices it is throwing up error.  Has anyone faced the same issue before?.

Any possible solutions are welcome.

Thanks a lot.

#Twincat3 #Twincat #PLC #Beckhoff #hmi #SPS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Python?

Comment: What is the error that is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

What module is before `KL2502`? If it is an `EL` module, you need [BK1250](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/i-o/ethercat-terminals/ek1xxx-bk1xx0-ethercat-coupler/bk1250.html) module to connect Bus terminals and EtherCAT terminals.

One `BK1250` is enough, but the order is important.
First, the PLC, then `EL` modules, coupler and `KL` modules. Something like this should work fine:

`CX9020 > EL9189 > EL9188 > EL1809 > EL2809 > BK1250 > KL2502`.

If any more `EL` modules were to be added, they should be placed between `EL2809` and `BK1250`. If any more `KL` modules were to be added, they should be placed after `KL2502`

Comment: Hello Jacek, Thank you for your reply. I have connected the modules in the following order. First the plc CX9020 then the PWM module KL2502 then the power cards EL9189 and EL9188, then the IO modules EL1809 and EL2809. So, one coupler BK1250 is enough to connect all these modules or I need other modules too. Kindly do reply.  Thank you

Comment: @Prasanth I have edited my answer with further details :)